# Create Link to External Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am trying to create an external link to each individual listing's assigned website address. Using the following code: (The listing website is saved as **google.com**)

`<a href="<%= listing.website %>">External Link</a>`

Takes me to:

localhost:3000/google.com

Is there any way to generate a link that would go to www.google.com instead of trying to find a route in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's bringing you to `localhost:3000/google.com` it's probably because the string you are passing to the `href` attribute is not a full qualified URL.

In fact, if in HTML you write

```
<a href="google.com">External Link</a>
```

The string will be appended to the current page path. You should make sure that the input you pass always contains the schema. If the input never contains that, then you can assume it's `http://`

```
<a href="http://<%= listing.website %>">External Link</a>
```

But this is not really a solution, just a workaround. You should definitely make sure that when you populate the `website` URL, you store a complete URL. In fact, some sites may require `https`.

In Rails you normally use the `url_for` and `link_to` helpers to generate an URL, but they will both cause the same issue unless you pass a full URL.

```
<%= link_to "External Link", "http://#{listing.website}" %>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. Will accept the answer when the time limit is over.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the [Rails way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-links):

```
<%= link_to 'External Link', "http://#{listing.website}" %>
```

Comment: This is not gonna work if the input is not a fully qualified hostname. It will simply return the string, causing exactly the same issue described by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the protocol.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Do you get it? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com", target: "_blank">External Link</a>
```